# Set label or text field to annotation title

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

Edit: Original Statement: 
I have a navigation controller embedded with a mapView on one view controller and it push segues into a second view controller by the use of a callout. The User hits the info key on the callout and they segue into the second view controller where they have to fill out a form. Once they hit the back key in the second view controller navigation bar, how would I link the first two lines of the form they filled out to be the title and subtitle of the pin?

Update: I've gone mad, because I have googled and re-made my XCode project to fulfill this one objective. I don't like to leave tasks uncompleted. I am getting nil for my string and text field when I return back towards the first view controller.

**first view controller.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "mapKit/Mapkit.h"
#import "thePinsViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, MKAnnotation, thePinsViewController> {

    MKMapView *mapViewing;

    MKPointAnnotation *annot;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapViewing;

@end
```

**first view controller.m file**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;

// This is your IBOutlet
@synthesize mapViewing;

// Initiate when the user holds the map to place a pin
- (void) addGestureRecognizerToMapView {

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];

    // User needs to press for [insert number in decimal format] seconds
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;

    [mapViewing addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
}

// This method fires when you add a pin
- (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        return;
    }

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView: mapViewing];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [mapViewing convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapViewing];

    annot = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

    annot.title = @"a";

    annot.subtitle = @"SubTitle";

    annot.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;

    [mapViewing addAnnotation:annot];

}

// This is your manual callout box
// with a rightDisclosureButton embedded in it
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)sender viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@""];

    // This gives the user permission to see or not see the callout box
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    // This is the info button in the callout box
    UIButton *rightDisclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightDisclosureButton;

    return annotationView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    thePinsViewController *scoobydoo = [[thePinsViewController alloc] init];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"heylisten" sender:view];

    scoobydoo.delegate = self;
}

- (void) didFirstFieldChange:(NSString*)newValue{

    // Change your annotation title here
    annot.title = newValue;
}

- (void) didSecondFieldChange:(NSString*)newValue{

    // Change your annotation title here
    annot.subtitle = newValue;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [mapViewing setDelegate:self];

    [self addGestureRecognizerToMapView];
}
```

**second view controller.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol thePinsViewController <NSObject>

- (void) didFirstFieldChange:(NSString*)newValue;
- (void) didSecondFieldChange:(NSString*)newValue;

@end

@interface thePinsViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<thePinsViewController> delegate;

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *helloWorldTextField;

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *helloWorldTextField2;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *helloWorldString;

@end
```

**second view controller.m file**

```
#import "thePinsViewController.h"

@interface thePinsViewController ()

@end

@implementation thePinsViewController

@synthesize helloWorldTextField;

@synthesize helloWorldTextField2;

@synthesize helloWorldString;

- (void) firstFieldChanged{

    if ( [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didFirstFieldChange:)] ){

        [self.delegate didFirstFieldChange:helloWorldTextField.text];
    }
}

- (void) secondFieldChanged{

    if ( [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didSecondFieldChange:)] ){

        [self.delegate didSecondFieldChange:helloWorldTextField2.text];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    helloWorldString = helloWorldTextField.text;
}
```

Comment: Hey, @rmaddy, what happens to stack overflow questions that go months without answering and forgotten about in the haystack? Are we able to copy the text in the post, delete the post, and re-ask the question again?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a delegate pattern to pass the info from your second view controller back to your first view controller.

***PinInformationViewController.h***

```
@protocol PinInformationViewControllerProtocol <NSObject>

- (void) didFirstFieldChange:(NSString*)newValue;
- (void) didSecondFieldChange:(NSString*)newValue;

@end

@interface PinInformationViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PinInformationViewControllerProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

***PinInformationViewController.m***

```
- (void) firstFieldChanged{
    if ( [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didFirstFieldChange:)] ){
        [self.delegate didFirstFieldChange:myTextField.text];
    }
}

- (void) secondFieldChanged{
    if ( [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didSecondFieldChange:)] ){
        [self.delegate didSecondFieldChange:myOtherTextField.text];
    }
}
```

***FirstViewController.m***

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    pinInformationViewController *scoobydoo = [[pinInformationViewController alloc]init];

    scoobydoo.delegate = self;

    annot.title = scoobydoo.helloWorldString;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"heylisten" sender:view];
}

- (void) didFirstFieldChange:(NSString*)newValue{
    // Change your annotation title here
}

- (void) didSecondFieldChange:(NSString*)newValue{
    // Change your annotation subtitle here
}
```

Comment: God Bless you kind person @agy! I have placed everything in its designated locations. The only error I am receiving so far is for @property (nonatomic, weak) id<SecondViewControllerProtocol> delegate; The error message displays: "Cannot find protocol declaration for SecondViewControllerProtocol". Shall I have placed PinInformationViewController in there?

Comment: Awesome, awesome @agy, I'm getting there. Now my scoobydoo.delegate = self is saying: " Assigning to 'id<PinInformationViewControllerProtocol>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong' ". In my FirstViewController, should I put anything in these symbols: < Somethingsomethingprotocol  > ??

Comment: You should add <PinInformationViewControllerProtocol> in the interface of FirstViewController to indicate that  conforms to the protocol. Please read some book about Cocoa and objective c